# Is it possible to convert a linear, time-variant (LTV) dynamical system into a time invariant system (LTI)?

Tags: dynamical-systems, vector-fields, control-theory, linear-control

Lets consider a dynamical system, whose state transition matrix is defined by $A(t)$, where size of A is $2$ x $2$ matrix. Can't we change $A(t)$ into $\hat{A}$, where $\hat{A}$ is a $3$x$3$ constant matrix, by introducing new state that incorporates time?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: No, you can't. If you have a new state that measures time, your system will become nonlinear, at best, bilinear. For instance, if we have $\dot{x}(t)=tx(t)$, then we can define $\dot{y}(t)=1$ and $\dot{x}(t)=y(t)x(t)$. In some cases, it may be possible to find a basis change such that, in that basis, the system is LTI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible if you mean  a system of the form
$$
\dot{x}=Ax+Bu
$$
with arbitrary initial condition. However if you are ok with a constant offset like
$$
\dot{x}=Ax+Bu+d
$$
then it is possible in some very special cases. For example
$$
\dot{x}=-x+u+t
$$
can be converted by
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=-x+y+u\\
\dot{y}&=1
\end{align}
$$
Strictly speaking this is not linear but affine. It can even be made linear by introducing another state and fixing initial conditions:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=-x+y+u\\
\dot{y}&=z\\
\dot{z}&=0\\
y(0)&=0\\
z(0)&=1
\end{align}
$$
and $x(0)$ arbitrary. This can be extended to more complicated situations. For example
$$
\dot{x}=-x+u+\sin(t)
$$
can be converted to
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}&=-x+y+u\\
\dot{y}&=z\\
\dot{z}&=-y\\
y(0)&=0\\
z(0)&=1
\end{align}
$$
and $x(0)$ arbitrary. If this is useful or not depends on your specific problem.